# Mysql date problem

Tags: php, mysql

i have a date field in db.

1. I want all the data between Saturday Sunday and Monday .
2. Of this data i want only 1 record that is record whose date is the next coming date

Hope i make my self clear

Comment: What is your question? Which weekdays do you mean, all of them or those of a specific week?

Comment: How about reversing your requirements? Grap the next date first and then check if it's Sat, Sun or Mon.

Comment: If you are looking for an select-statement please write down some information like table descriptin (name of cells,...). try to wirte down your goals... maybe use pseudo code for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date)>0  AND (DAYOFWEEK(date) in (1,2,7)   ORDER BY date   LIMIT 0,1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(date) as wd FROM table WHERE wd > 1 AND wd < 6 AND date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$from = strtotime('saturday');
$to   = strtotime('tueseday') - 1; // whole monday

mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= ' . $from . ' AND date <= ' . $to . ' ORDER BY date LIMIT 1');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the data you need from the database:

```
//once you've connected to the DB
$db_query= "SELECT * FROM table 
            WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date)>0 
            AND (DAYOFTHEWEEK(date)<3 OR DAYOFTHEWEEK(date)==7)
            ORDER BY date
            LIMIT 0,1";//limits it to one (date) result
$result=mysql_query($db_query);
if(!$result){ die('ERROR: Query failed.'); }
```

This will print the resultant row on screen:

```
while($ROW=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<p>date: {$ROW['date']}</p>";
    //do the same for all the fields you want like so:
    echo "<p>other field: {$ROW['other field']}</p>";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```